# Не работает message.content

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу для теста сделать бота, который будет повторять все сообщения на сервере, но когда я использую `message.content`, то бот туда почему-то ничего не записывает.

Я также пробовал вывести просто `message`, но он мне вывел всю информацию про сообщение, но ни слова про его содержание.

Вот код:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Бот успешно подключен к серверу!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("omg message")
    if message.author != client.user:
        await message.channel.send(message)


client.run('')
```

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает `message content intent`.
Выставляете галочку здесь (зайдите в [портал разработчиков](https://discord.com/developers/applications), нажмите на вашего бота, перейдите во вкладку `Bot`):
[image: скрин]
В коде:

```py
# intents.dm_messages = True # разкомментируйте, если хотите получать сообщения в ЛС бота
intents.guild_messages = True # сообщения на серверах
intents.message_content = True # содержимое сообщения
```

Comment: Чёёрт, опередили)

Comment: работает спасибо